# How to add FormsAuthentication to Blazor application

Tags: blazor, forms-authentication

I have a Blazor server application (.Net 5) where I am using the 'Individual Accounts' authentication type.

After the user has logged in, I need to create a FormsAuthenticationTicket (SetAuthCookie) for the logged in user and then redirect them to another page.

Likewise I need to clear the ticket after the user signs out (and I will need to clear the blazor login if the  FormsAuthenticationTicket expires).

In the old ASP.Net days, the ticket would have been created after the call to Membership.ValidateUser(), followed by a response.redirect().

Does anyone have a link to an example of how to do this in Blazor?

I have found code in LogOut.cshtml that makes the call to SigninManager.SignOutAsync() which I can amend for signout, but cannot find the routine for when the login is validated.

Comment: In `Login.cshtml` ?  Maybe you have to scaffold some items.

Comment: Thanks, I have not been able to see what to overload.  Login.cshtml just makes a call to SigninManager from memory (and Logout I think is more basic).  I suspect that I might need to create a custom SigninManager and add it to startup.cs which seems a bit of effort.   I don't want to change the existing functionality - I just want to decorate it with a bit more.